# Conditional $or in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to do from and to date querying in MongoDB. My solution is good when there is no from and to query parameters, but it crashes when I write this in URL.

What's the problem or maybe you have better solution for this.

Error

> {"stringValue":""{ fromDate: 'Sat Dec 31 2022' }"","kind":"string","value":{"fromDate":"Sat Dec 31 2022"},"path":"date","reason":null,"valueType":"Object","statusCode":400}

Route

```js
router.get("/:_id/logs", (req, res) => {
  const fromDate = new Date(req.query.from).toDateString();
  const toDate = new Date(req.query.to).toDateString();
  User.findById(req.params._id)
    .then((user) => {
      Exercise.find({
        $and: [
          { user: req.params._id },
          fromDate !== "Invalid Date"
          ? { date: { $gte: { fromDate } } }
          : {},
          toDate !== "Invalid Date" ? { date: { $lte: { toDate } } } : {},
        ],
      })
        .limit(+req.query.limit)
        .sort({ date: 1 })
        .exec()
        .then((exercises) =>
          res.json({
            username: user.username,
            userId: user._id,
            count: exercises.length,
            logs: exercises,
          })
        )
        .catch((err) => res.json({ ...err, statusCode: 400 }));
    })
    .catch((err) => res.json({ ...err, statusCode: 400 }));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it's simpler to build the query operator first:

```
const fromDate = new Date(req.query.from).toDateString();
const toDate = new Date(req.query.to).toDateString();

const dateOperator = {};
if (fromDate !== "Invalid Date") {
  dateOperator.$gte = fromDate;
}
if (toDate !== "Invalid Date") {
  dateOperator.$lte = toDate;
}

Exercise.find({
        $and: [
          { user: req.params._id },
          { date: dateOperator },
        ],
      })
```